# If $\sin^2x+a^2\cos^2x=b^2$ and $a^2\sin^2x+\cos^2x=k^2$, then $k^2=1+a^2-b^2$

Tags: trigonometry

> If
>   $$\sin^2x+a^2\cos^2x=b^2$$
>   $$a^2\sin^2x+\cos^2x=k^2$$
>   then why is
>   $$k^2=1+a^2-b^2$$
>   ?

Comment: Note that by adding the two equations, you get $$k^2+b^2=(1+a^2)(\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x) = \, ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Sum the two equations to get $$(a^2+1)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=b^2+k^2$$
You obviously know $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It kinda make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2 x+a^2 \cos ^2x=b^2$$
$$\implies (1-\cos^2 x)+a^2 \cos ^2x=b^2$$

Now, substitute $\cos^2x$ in second equation to get the desired answer.